# How to send data form first server to other and get other server response in first server?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, request, server

I have two servers. One server has all api what I need to use from another server.

**Server 1 urls**

- `http://127.0.0.1:9000/url` (get, post, patch, delete)
- `http://127.0.0.1:9000/otherurl` (get, post, patch, delete)
- `http://127.0.0.1:9000/anotherurl` (get, post, patch, delete)

**Server 2 urls**

- `http://127.0.0.1:4000/first` (get, post, patch, delete)
- `http://127.0.0.1:4000/second` (get, post, patch, delete)
- `http://127.0.0.1:4000/third` (get, post, patch, delete)

I want make a request to **server 2**, this server make request to **server 1** and **server 2** send me response from **server 1**.
I want to use a [request lib](https://github.com/request/request) and pass data through pipes.

**Example (pseudocode)**

```
'use strict';

var app = request('express'),
    request = require('request');

app.post('/first', function(req, res, next) {
    request({
        baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/',
        url: 'url',
        method: 'post',
        data: {/* something like req.pipe() */}
    }, function(err, otherRes) {
        res.writeHead(otherRes.statusCode, otherRes.headers);
        otherRes.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this middleware [connect-modrewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-modrewrite).

```
app.use(modRewrite([
'http://127.0.0.1:4000/first  http://127.0.0.1:9000/url [P]',
'http://127.0.0.1:4000/second http://127.0.0.1:9000/otherurl [P]',
'http://127.0.0.1:4000/third  http://127.0.0.1:9000/anotherurl [P]'
]));
```

Just try this code in your first sever.

Comment: No, I need to use `request lib`